# Remove all code of a JSON file except for specific value string in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list of artists in a JSON file. I would like to remove all the code in the file except for their names. The code looks like this:

```
},
            {
                "name": "Sadek",
                "mbid": "52940c47-5d0a-4995-bbf8-361a365a48a0",
                "match": "0.100799",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Sadek",
                "image": [
                    {
                        "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/34s/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png",
                        "size": "small"
                    },
                    {
```

I would like to remove everything but the containing string of the "name" value (Sadek).

The closest I could get was finding the name value in Notepad++ using `.*("name":  *).*` but I couldn't figure a way to delete everything but the containing string of the name value.

Comment: Do you have to use Notepad++? A python script for exemple would do this perfectly and quickly

Comment: I can use python, if you wouldn't mind sharing the details for the script I would appreciate it. I found a website however that works perfect for this: https://jsonpath.com/

Comment: Why regex? Using an actual JSON parser (like Python has) would be so much easier.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 solutions in Python. Written and tested with your shown samples Only.

***1st solution:*** Using regex in `re.findall` method.

```
import re

value="""},
            {
                "name": "Sadek",
                 "mbid": "52940c47-5d0a-4995-bbf8-361a365a48a0",
                "match": "0.100799",
                 "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Sadek",
                 "image": [
                     {
                        "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/34s/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png",
                        "size": "small"
                    },
                    {
"""

re.findall(r'(?:^.*?{\s+)("name":[^,]*),(?:.*$)',value,re.M) 
['"name": "Sadek"']
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using `json` library.

```
import json
with open('Input_file.json', 'r') as fcc_file:
    fcc_data = json.load(fcc_file)

for j in fcc_data:
   if j == 'name':                   
     print(f'{j} {fcc_data[j]}')
```